# Connect to 32-Bit MS Access DB in a 64-Bit VB .Net application

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I am  very new to programming so I will require some extra help on figuring this out. I have a VB .NET application that provides an Add-In for a 64-Bit application. The task I am trying to accomplish is to open a connection to a 32-Bit MS Access database and lookup data from a table. Where this falls apart is the fact that a 64-Bit application cannot connect with a 32-Bit database. You can probably tell from my explanation that I barely know what I am talking about.

Everything I have researched on this topic comes to the same conclusion that I need to use an interprocess communication but do not explain how this is done and what I am required to do to make this happen.

Here is my connection setup in the VB .Net application:

```
Public Class MSDatabase
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader

    Public Sub LoadDatabase()
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        dataFile = "\\server3\databases\Quotes.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    End Sub

    Public Function LookUpPart(D As Double, E As Double, F As Double, G As Double, Grade As String) As Boolean

        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "SELECT PartNumber, D, E, F, G, Grade FROM Parts"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read()
            If D = dr("D") And E = dr("E") And F = dr("F") And G = dr("G") And Grade = dr("Grade") Then
                Return True
            End If
        End While
        myConnection.Close()
        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

This fails when I try to open the connection with the error message stating that the provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered on the local machine.

What I would like to know is how to use interprocess communication to set this up as a 32-Bit application called from my 64-Bit application.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's no such thing as a 32-bit Access table.  The table just is.  It's the OLE DB provider that is 32-bit or 64-bit.  Why would you not simply compile the app to target the x86 platform and run in a 32-bit process?  IPC to get Access data sounds rather silly.

Comment: Hmmm, read the question more carefully and I now see the issue.  Can I assume that installing 64-bit ACE is out of the question?

Comment: Yes sorry I should have worded that differently. I have to use the 32-bit OLE DB provider because the MS Access application being used is 32-Bit. I cannot target x86 because it then the dll for the Add-In will have to be registered as 32-Bit and will not run for the 64-Bit program it is written for. Than you for your reply! That was fast!

Comment: This Add-In is to be distributed to multiple machines and I would like to look for a solution that does not require the user to install additional drivers and such to run the Add-In.

Comment: I guess the first thing that comes to mind is a 32-bit commandline application that retrieved data into a `DataSet` and then called `WriteXml` on that to write it to a file that your 64-bit application could read.  Your 64-bit app could invoke it using `Process.Start` and then read the file after calling `WaitForExit` on the `Process`.  You could also presumably use a `NetworkStream` to pass data directly and avoid the file system.

Comment: I would prefer to use a NetworkStream over a file system.

Comment: Then you would a `TcpListener` and `TcpClient`.  Once the connection is made, you get a `NetworkStream` from the `TcpClient` and then read and/or write to it like any other `Stream`.  Note that the `WriteXml` and `ReadXml` methods of the `DataSet` class both accept a `Stream` as an argument.

Comment: So I can create a TCP socket connection with the listener in my 64-Bit application and the client in a separate 32 bit console application that is started by the 64-Bit application using Process.Start and then send my request to the client to look up data in the access table and send back data?

Comment: Yes.  Bittedness is irrelevant when communicating between processes.  It's only within a process where the bittedness has to be consistent, hence you can't load a 32-bit OLE DB provider in a 64-bit application because it's all one process.

Comment: Got it working! Thank you very much for your help and guidance. Would you like to write this into an answer so I can accept it? What I did was create a class with a public shared sub main() that acted as the client in the TCP socket connection living in my application. From that sub I used <start.process> before starting the client socket to run a separate module that is my TcpListener, which does my database work and sends back results to the client in my application. I did have to build the TcpListener module in the x86 platform in order for it to work. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [jmcilhinney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584183/jmcilhinney) for their help with solving this issue. Read the comments under the question to see how we arrive at this solution.

SOLUTION: Using interprocess communication through a TCP socket connection you can pass data back and forth regardless of the bittedness of the host and client. In this case, the 64-Bit vb .net program written for an Add-In to another software can setup a `TcpClient` that uses `Process.Start` to first run a `TcpListener` in a console application developed for the x86 platform and then send the listener information for the database communication. The listener being a 32-Bit console application is able to find and use the 32-Bit provider for the OLEDB connection and pull the needed data from the Access DB. The data is then sent back to the client in the 64-Bit application.

For the TCP socket connection you can use a simple YouTube tutorial on a client/server TCP connection for vb.net.

For sending data I used a delimiter so that the data could easily be separated on the other end using `Split`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have updated the answer to not include links.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and solved it by following the [the instructions found here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments/) (look for the section titled "The Solution"). There you'll find a link to the appropriate driver you need to install.

The install seems to be necessary because with Office 2010 Microsoft changed the driver for accessing Access, Excel and so on. So it's not a problem with your code, but the environment it runs in.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Unfortunately I have already tried this and did not succeed. You cannot install the 64-Bit driver when 32-Bit office products exist on the machine. Since my application must run on the 64-Bit platform it will only look for the 64-Bit provider (This is my understanding).

Comment: That is kind of a problem. I also ran into that problem and could only resolve it by replacing the 32bit office. I ended up providing a 32bit and a 64bit version of my product. I hope you find a better solution.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. Your answer is greatly appreciated!